# how to access the session variable in the file routes.php using cakephp 3 beta?

Tags: cakephp

I'm needing to access a session variable in the routes.php file.
If not possible, is there any way to set a variable in controller and access variable in routes.php?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can start sessions this early as far as I know.

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
$value = CakeSession::read('your-value');
```